# Lambda@Edge when triggered Dynamodb giving 503 Error

Tags: amazon-cloudfront, aws-lambda-edge

I am trying to invoke `Lambda` through cloudfront viewer request . Here is my Lambda code

```
'use strict';
const AWS = require("aws-sdk");
const docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    /* Get request */
    const request = event.Records[0].cf.request;
    const requestbody = Buffer.from(request.body.data, 'base64').toString();
    const data = JSON.parse(requestbody);
    const Id = data.Name;
    console.log(Id);

    /* Generate body for response */
    const body = 
     '<html>\n'
     + '<head><title>Hello From Lambda@Edge</title></head>\n'
     + '<body>\n'
     + '<h1>You clicked more than 10 Times </h1>\n'
     + '</body>\n'
     + '</html>';
    var params = {
        TableName: "Test",
         ProjectionExpression: "#V,#N",
         KeyConditionExpression: "#N = :v1",
         ExpressionAttributeNames: { 
                  "#N" : "Name",
                  "#V" : "Value"
                                  },
  ExpressionAttributeValues: {
  ":v1": Id
  }
 };
var querydb = docClient.query(params).promise();
querydb.then(function(data) {
    console.log(data.Items[0].Value);
    if(data.Items[0].Value >= 11){
    const response = {
        status: '200',
        body: body,
    };
    callback(null, response);
}else {
    callback(null,request);
}
}).catch(function(err) {
  console.log(err);
});
};
```

When i triggered the same lambda through console it is giving correct response. But when i deployed through Cloudfront it is giving `503 Error`. But i had tried the same code withcode `Dynamodb Client` it worked perfectly fine. Here is the working one

```
'use strict';
const AWS = require("aws-sdk");
const docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    /* Get request */
    const request = event.Records[0].cf.request;
    const requestbody = Buffer.from(request.body.data, 'base64').toString();
    const data = JSON.parse(requestbody);

    /* Generate body for response */
    const body = 
     '<html>\n'
     + '<head><title>Hello From Lambda@Edge</title></head>\n'
     + '<body>\n'
     + '<h1>You clicked more than 10 Times </h1>\n'
     + '</body>\n'
     + '</html>';
     if(data.Value >= 10){
    const response = {
        status: '200',
        body: body,
    };

    callback(null, response);
}
else {
 callback(null, request);
}
};
```

I had given full dynamodb permissions to the lambda@edge.

Any help is appreciated
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where have you specified region for DyanamoDB?
 It is possible that Lambda@Edge is executing in a region where your DDB table is missing. 
Have a look at AWS doc on [region's order of precedence](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/setting-region.html#setting-region-order-of-precedence). You can also look at this [L@E workshop code](https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-lambda-edge-workshops/blob/master/Workshop1/Lab7_DynamicDatastoreSelection/ws-lambda-at-edge-generate-home-page.js) and [documentation](https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-lambda-edge-workshops/tree/master/Workshop1/Lab7_DynamicDatastoreSelection#3-modify-a-lambda-function) for more details on calling DDB.
On a side note: A viewer facing Lambda function, making a call to a cross region dynamodb table will have negative effects on your latency. Not sure about your use case but see if it is possible to move this call to an origin facing event or make async call to ddb.

Comment: Thanks @Mr.Ocean . I am under assumption that it would take default region name `us-east-1` since i am running this lambda@edge from N.Virginia. This line works like a charm `const ddbEU = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient({apiVersion: '2012-10-08', region: 'us-east-1'});` . I even tried like this `AWS.config.update({ region: "us-east-1", endpoint: "http://dynamodb.us-east-1.amazonaws.com" });` but it didnt worked.

Comment: @Private Lambda@Edge executes from whatever region is closest to the client making the request. So if I made a request that invoked that Lambda it would probably happen in one of the European data centers. Lambda@Edge code is always distributed depending on your CloudFront distribution configuration. This also means that if you wanted to see logs for that Lambda, you would need to go looking in the region the error happened, not us-east-1.