# Making DynamoDb calls from lambda@edge for viewer-request events

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-cloudfront

I am looking to use viewer-request event to perform some checks for cloud-fronted S3 requests. For that I need to make a dynamodb call. However, viewer-request events are maxed out at 1MB of function size (including libraries), while "aws-sdk" npm (used to perform dynamodb calls) itself is ~5MB.
I see in some posts (like [Lambda@Edge when triggered Dynamodb giving 503 Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53235627/lambdaedge-when-triggered-dynamodb-giving-503-error)) that people have been able to use "aws-sdk" with viewer-request. How is that being done? Is there a reliable lite version or a dynamodb specific version of the lib?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `aws-sdk` is included in the Node.js runtime for Lambda@Edge.

You don't need to package it, you can simply do:

```js
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
```